# Is there a way to disable synchronized editing in VS Code 1.76.2?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to split the editor and have side-by-side panes so that I can view the original content in one pane, and my edits in the other pane. However, when I split the editor, my changes appear in both panes simultaneously. Is there a way to do this in VS Code 1.76.2? I thought this was possible in older versions.

I have tried splitting the editor, and I have tried searching the settings for "Synchronized Editing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature and with respect, I don't think what you're proposing makes sense. The whole point of the split editor feature is that you are looking at *the same* content being edited- just able see two independent editors with independent scrolling.

Purportedly though (by you), such a feature did exist in VS Code 1.5x.

If you want to see a view comparing your changes with the original, use the `Git: Open Changes` command to open the diff view for the current file being edited, or just click on the diff decorations in the gutter (the part of the UI between the line number indicators and the text content being edited), which opens up a small panel showing the diff in that line's vicinity.

If you actually want to have two independent contents to edit, then make a new copy of the file.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252732/discussion-on-answer-by-user-is-there-a-way-to-disable-synchronized-editing-in-v); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.